# Matlab image sharpening error: 'size isn't same' after converting to double

Tags: matlab, image-processing

In Matlab when i try to convolute an .tif image with  `filter[0 1 0; 1 -4 1; 0 1 0]` then sharpen it by subtract the original image from the filtered image it says that the matrix should be same class and size

convert the image to double then sharp it then it says the size isn't same

Comment: Reverse engineering? Please take a few seconds to read the tag information before adding a tag. I’ve added a more relevant tag, putting in the right tags means that the people that can answer your question get to see it.

Comment: Please read [mre]. Unless you show code, we can only make assumptions about what you did. No amount of descriptions is going to be as useful and insightful as an actual bit of working code. Please [edit] your post to include runnable, minimal code. You should also copy-paste the full error message.

Comment: it would really help if you decide sharing some of your code with the readers attempting to help you.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be to use the "conv2(img, filter, 'same');"

To keep the output image size the same as the input image size. I'm guessing this is the problem.

Edit, here is what I think should happen.

```
Img = double((imread('...'));
if (numel(size(Img)) >= 3)
    % grab the colormap and do computations on grayscale image
    [Img, cmap] = rgb2ind(Img);
end

Out = conv2(Img, filter, 'same');
```

Images should be same size and and both be double class.